# Mac OS X Mojave Font thinner on Chrome - how to fix?

Tags: css, macos, macos-mojave

Every font is thinner on Mac OS X Mojave on Chrome. See references like ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/8ol061/anyone_else_feel_the_text_is_slightly_less_bold/) or [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51132)).

That is my main problem and I need your suggestions what to do. I'm currently developing a website, but now the design looks way off. On Safari it's okay. But should I "wait" until there is a fix?

The reason is that they removed subpixel font aliasing.

What does this mean for a CSS developer?

Is there a fix somehow?

Comment: You can mess around with the [font-smooth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) property, the `subpixel-antialiased` value might be your best bet since it's supposed to sharpen text on non-retina monitors, but other than that, you're pretty much at the mercy of Apple.

Comment: @APAD1 but it's crazy now, now every website looks so different... hard time!

Comment: all applications on OSX mojave look terrible -  fonts in XCode look horrendous too so its not just a Chrome issue

Comment: Tried every variation of font-smoothing in CSS to no avail. Looks like your best bet might just be to use a thicker font variation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this command in terminal:

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

Comment: I'm just curious, but how does it help me as a UI developer? I mean okay I see it as before but now I've customers with mac OS Mojave and they see it differently...

Comment: An easier way is to go to Preferences, then General, and at the bottom uncheck the 'Use font smoothing when available'.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!
@KaiJ it isn't the same thing

Comment: did not help at all

Comment: @JitendraVyas well, why shouldn't I? He shared a helpful answer and for some people, it is working. I have to live with the change...

Answer (score 4):

> An easy fix I discovered was to disable the font smoothing disabler.

All you have to do is open up your Terminal application (<kbd>COMMAND (⌘)</kbd> +<kbd>SPACE</kbd> then search for Terminal) and run the following command.

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

Here, I made a nice image of entering this thing in my terminal:

[image: macos font issue]

**EXPLANATION**:

We are switching off the disabler which is disabling the font smoothing process on non-retina screens. In simple words enabling the font smoothing.

> I wrote more details about how I found this setting in the [fix macOS font](https://ahmadawais.com/fix-macos-mojave-font-rendering-issue/) post.

**NEXT STEPS**:

I recommend you restart your computer now, but logging out and in should fix it.

[image: macos log out in]

> You can also Log out with <kbd>COMAND (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT (⇧)</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: [off-topic] What are the modifications you have made to your agnoster-zsh theme? Will you be able to share the settings?

Comment: I believe you emailed me. I sent you a detailed answer. It's the suit of  Shades of Purple themes I made check em out here https://github.com/ahmadawais/shades-of-purple-vscode#put-shades-of-purple-in-other-places and you want Zsh theme and iTerm2 theme for above.